# 800A0401 vbs error

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I copied my excel vb code into a vbs and I know there are semantic/logic differences, would really appreciate some guidance. I'm getting the error above for "**Next i**" (line 44) - which is essentially an integer.

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\midi\Desktop\IT\E\PRF.xlsm")
   For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets
   msgbox wsheet.name

next

Sub RefreshConns()
    ' Refreshes the connections according to the specified cells

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Sheets("Run Macro").Activate
Dim connName 
Dim connStr 
Dim sqltext ' SQL text

Dim TempconnName 
Dim TempconnStr 
Dim Tempsqltext ' temporary SQL text
Dim i 
Dim SiteName 

SiteName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
'MsgBox (SiteName)
For i = 5 To 11
connName = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
connStr = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
sqltext = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
'MsgBox (connName)

TempconnStr = Replace(connStr, "SiteNameVBA", SiteName)
'Debug.Print (ActiveWorkbook.Connections(connName).ODBCConnection.Connection)
'MsgBox (TempconnStr)
'Tempsqltext = Replace(sqltext, "SiteNameVBA", SiteName)

'On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(connName).ODBCConnection.CommandText = sqltext
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(connName).ODBCConnection.Connection = "ODBC;" & TempconnStr
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(connName).Refresh

Next i

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub

Public Function ZeroToBlank(x String) String
If x = "0" Then
    ZeroToBlank = ""
Else
    ZeroToBlank = x
End If
End Function
```

Comment: In VBScript use `Next`, not `Next i`.

Comment: In VBScript you always use `Next` rather than `Next i` or something similar. Also, VBScript can only control Excel if you create an Excel Application Object. Also -- you *never* give typenames in declarations in VBScript, since everything is variant. Really, you should find a couple of good examples of a VBScript program interacting with Excel, and make sure you understand that code before trying to modify a VBA macro to run as a VBScript program.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you very much! I took your recommendation and found a couple of great starting points. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Next` closes a `for` loop. But you don't have any for loops. Delete both lines with `next` on them.

EG As before you can't declare anything except as variant which is done by omitting the `as type`. You just don't think about type.

```
Public Function ZeroToBlank(x)
    If x = "0" Then
        ZeroToBlank = ""
    Else
        ZeroToBlank = x
    End If
End Function
```